# Function to check element is not displayed in protractor

Tags: protractor, end-to-end

How can I check that an element is not displayed in protractor?

I am interested in a generic function with parameters that returns true or false. I would use it multiple times in a test.

Comment: Have you tried using `invisibilityOf()` expected condition function?

Answer (score 6):

[`.isDisplayed()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isDisplayed) is your function:

```
expect(elm.isDisplayed()).toBe(false);  // elm is not visible
```

Comment: This won't work -- as soon as you call thing.isDisplayed(), protractor will throw the following error:

`- Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .thing)`

Comment: @ginna well, we are talking about visibility check here. If your element does not exist in the DOM at all, you would need `.isPresent()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you're not doing an expectation but rather you're waiting for something to disappear you can do:

```
browser.wait(function () {
  return elm.isDisplayed().then(function(displayed) {
    return !displayed;
  });
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use Protractor's built-in Expected Conditions.invisibilityOf method.  It doesn't return true / false, but does throw an error if false.

```
import { browser, by, element, ExpectedConditions } from 'protractor';

const elToFind = element(by.css('.thing')),

it('elToFind is hidden or not present', () => {
  try {
    browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(elToFind), 5000);
  } catch(err) {
    // the statement threw an error (and thus is false)
    // continue your test here for the 'false' case
  } 
  // the statement executed successfully (and thus is true) 
  // continue your test here for the 'true' case
});
```

If the above throws an error, your test will fail.  Otherwise, it passes.

Documentation: 
https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.invisibilityOf

Comment: but the OP wants true or false. You'd need to embed this in a try catch to give that.

Comment: Good point, thanks @jeremy, updated to show try / catch solution

Comment: That is progress. But I think it is really requesting function(l: Locator):boolean{}. Then again, it is two years old, so probably the person who asked has moved on. Personally I think the way to go would be (assuming it should already be visible) to let elms=await element.all(loc); if elms.count==0 (no awiat here, b/c elms was resolved already) return false; let retval=false; elms.foreach if it's visible, retval=true; return retval. Probably some awaits on that, but you get the idea. On the other hand, from what I have seen on the site alecxe is never wrong.

Comment: @jeremy feel free to add another answer, def interesting to see ideas of how to solve

Comment: The problem, I think, with your current approach (which followed my suggestion, sorry), is that in the async, await, selenium promise manager disabled world that is coming, it will kvetch about an unresolved promise rejection. That also turned out to mess up what I was suggesting above. There is a nice function that returns a promise to a boolean (so all ready for await) in https://github.com/hetznercloud/protractor-test-helper/blob/master/dist/waits.js called waitToBeNotDisplayed.